# Architecture - How to efficiently crawl the web with 10,000 machine?

Tags: algorithm, architecture, web-crawler, distributed-computing

Let’s pretend I have a network of 10,000 machines. I want to use all those machines to crawl the web as fast as possible. All pages should be downloaded only once. In addition there must be no single point of failure and we must minimize the number of communication required between machines. How would you accomplish this?

Is there anything more efficient than using [consistent hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing) to distribute the load across all machines and minimize communication between them?

Comment: This is probably a stupid answer, which is why I'm making it a mere comment. You could identify the 10,000 most common URL prefixes (via analysis or guessing, or by a random statistical sample) and allocate each prefix to a different machine. When a machine finds an embedded link to a URL with a different prefix, send a packet to the other machine giving the URL. This should result in low communication due to the fact that many sites are more likely to link to other pages in the same domain... but determining a good set of prefixes - one which results in good utilization - might be tricky.

Comment: You could also reserver a pool of leftover machines - say 100-1000 - to be used on an on-demand basis, in case a few machines get overloaded (popular prefixes).

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that each machine won't go through its queue at the same speed due to varying response time from servers and varying document sizes. I don't think that consistent hashing helps you much with this, unless you're willing to average the cost of each url download.

Comment: Have you looked at the wikipedia entry for distributed web crawling? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_web_crawling

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a distributed [Map Reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) system like [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) to divide the workspace.
2. If you want to be clever, or doing this in an academic context then try a [Nonlinear dimension reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_dimensionality_reduction).
3. Simplest implementation would probably be to use a hashing function on the *name space* key e.g. the domain name or URL.  Use a [Chord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_%28peer-to-peer%29) to assign each machine a subset of the hash values to process.

Answer (score 0):

One Idea would be to use work queues (directories or DB), assuming you will be working out storage such that it meets your criteria for redundancy.

\retrieve

\retrieve\server1

\retrieve\server...

\retrieve\server10000

\in-process

\complete

1.) All pages to be seeds will be hashed and be placed in the queue using the hash as a file root.

2.) Before putting in the queue you check the complete and in-process queues to make sure you don't re-queue

3.) Each server retrieves a random batch (1-N) files from the retrieve queue and attempts to move it to the private queue

4.) Files that fail the rename process are assumed to have been “claimed” by another process

5.) Files that can be moved are to be processed put a marker in in-process directory to prevent re-queuing.

6.) Download the file and place it into the \Complete queue

7.) Clean file out of the in-process and server directories

8.) Every 1,000 runs check the oldest 10 in-process files by trying to move them from their server queues back into the general retrieve queue.  This will help if a server hangs and also should load balance slow servers.

For the Retrieve, in-process and complete servers most file systems hate millions of files in 1 directory, Divide storage into segments based on the characters of the hash \abc\def\123\ would be the directory for file abcdef123FFFFFF…. If you were scaling to billions of downloads.

If you are using a mongo DB instead of a regular file store much of these problems would be avoided and you could benefit from the sharding etc…